# How can I lose the #VALUE error on Excel 'if' statement which uses a partial date match?

Tags: excel, date, excel-formula

This is my statement
 =IF((AND(C2>="*14:00*"+0,E2<="*12:00*"+0)),"Unassigned next AM","")

I know it's the date causing the issue but cannot find resolution.

Comment: If I enter 14:40 to C2 and 8:00 to E2, your formula works. What data do you have in those cells?

Comment: I would replace your time in quotes with Excel's built in timing system, e.g. `"14:00"` should be replaced with `TIME(14,0,0)`. Does this fix your problem?

Comment: It would help your question to show sample inputs and expected outputs, along with an explanation of exactly what the formula is supposed to be testing for.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following formula:

=IF(AND(C2>=14/24+0,E2<=12/24+0),"unassigned next AM","")

Hope this Helps.